# Canadian Provincial Health Care for Working Holiday is 100% necessary?

Tags: france, canada, health-insurance, working-holiday-visas

I am a Canadian citizen who has been out of the country (working in Japan) for the last three years. I wish to apply for the working holiday visa to France (visa 3D category), but am required to be covered by the provincial health care in addition to travel insurance for the duration of my stay in France. Since I have been out of the country for so long, my insurance has expired, and according to the health Ontario website, they won’t cover me out-of-country unless I stay in Canada for two years prior to my trip.

Has any Canadian been able to successfully go on any working holiday immediately after living for some time out of Canada? If I were to get comprehensive coverage from an insurance provider will the provincial coverage be negligible? Any advice from people with past experiences in this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would have expected France to look at coverage where you are resident, not your citizenship. Did you accidentally check a box indicating you were resident in Canada?

Comment: User has not returned to clarify questions, putting on hold.